# Are these variables in list comprehensions random?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm learning python from the dive into python 3 book and they really didn't explain if the variables in list comprehensions are random or not. here is an example ran in the python shell:

```
import os, glob

glob.glob('*.xml')                                 ①
    ['feed-broken.xml', 'feed-ns0.xml', 'feed.xml']

[os.path.realpath(f) for f in glob.glob('*.xml')]  ②
    ['c:\\Users\\pilgrim\\diveintopython3\\examples\\feed-broken.xml',
     'c:\\Users\\pilgrim\\diveintopython3\\examples\\feed-ns0.xml',
     'c:\\Users\\pilgrim\\diveintopython3\\examples\\feed.xml']
```

Where does the f come from? Is it random?

Comment: `glob.glob()` operates on the current directory. This command gets all `*.xml` files from it. There is rarely something *random* and when there is, it would most likely be explicitly mentioned.

Comment: What do you mean *"Is it random?"*? Do you mean *"how did the author decide to call it `f`?"*? We can't really answer that - I'd guess because it will be a string representing a **f**ile location, but you'd have to ask them. If you mean *"where is it defined?"*, then that's in `for f in`, exactly as with a vanilla `for` loop.

Comment: The name of the local variable `f` is *arbitrary* (i. e. you could have chosen any valid identifier).  It is hopefully and probably not *random*.

Comment: Just to give more detail: you're getting an almost gut-level emotional response from a lot of programmers.  Generally, we don't like *random* - in fact, we'll claim that there is no randomness in computing.  The only things a computer does is what we tell it, and in the end, there are some 1's and 0's that we know we caused to happen, commanding the computer.  Even random number generators aren't random, they're psuedorandom.  As others have said, you want the word *arbitrary* - up to the individual. As you grow as a programmer, you'll find we value precision in our words. :-)

Answer (score 3):

I assume you meant to ask if they are *arbitrary*. Yes, you could use any name instead of f here, e. g. `os.path.realpath(xmlfile) for xmlfile in glob.glob('*.xml')`.

Answer (score 0):

List comprehensions are a shorthand form for this pattern:

```
l = []
for <var> in <val>:
    l.append(<expression>)
```

The same thing as list comprehension:

```
[<expression> for <var> in <val>]
```

So the `f` in `os.path.realpath(f)` is named at `for f in ...`. You can choose any name you want. The only unusual thing is that you seem to reference the variable before you declare it, but that's just coincidental.

Answer (score 0):

No.

`glob.glob`, as you demonstrated, returns a list. The order of that list is defined by `glob`. When you iterate through it in the list comprehension, the order of iteration is the order of the list.

If you’re wondering why the files are being returned in the order they are, look into the ordering of results from `glob`.

Comment: His question is about the variable `f`, not the values.